# Map SQL Query to Data Object - J2EE spec

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, crud

We are upgrading our environment in house, we are currently using `Jersey -> Spring DI -> Spring JDBC` for all our data operations. and ofcourse JMS, schedulers,Dozer etc., and a lot other libraries are used based on need.

Our plan is to move towards complete J2EE spec, So to use `Jax-rs(jersey)/Jax-ws - > CDI ->  (???)`

Our application has a lot of tables(~5000) and data is not always from one table. Which j2ee spec allows us to perform CRUD operations on the database without us having to manually map the data to the DO?

I've looked at JPA, JDO, JDBC as options, but none of these can help us as it requires Entity mapped to the table, which is not an option. Our DO/Entity will be a join from more than one database table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move towards standard JavaEE, then JAX-RS (if possible I would avoid JAX-WS nowadays) CDI/EJB and JPA is the way to go, but as you already recognized you have to map database table to Entities. However you can join tables with `@JoinColumn` / `@JoinTable`.

With JDBC you get a low-level API in comparison with JPA and you do not have to map the tables into entities, but you probably have to write more boilerplate code.

In general I would also think about if it's possible to refactor this big application with 5000 tables into smaller business components.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for the answer. JPA may not work for us as all of the queries that we write are native sql each over couple of hundred lines and it is a lot of work for us to write entities for each of the table that we write, our's is a sql heavy application. Isnt there a J2EE spec that supports SQL only? apart from JPA?

Comment: JPA supports native SQL queries, but if you are only gonna use them (and no ORM) I would rather stick to JDBC, which is no JavaEE spec as such, but the standard "bridge" from Java to database and can also be used within an application server.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like we hit a dead end.